# Socket io multiple connections in react app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, websocket, socket.io

I am not pasting any code here because this is a very straight question.
In my parent component, I am trying to pass down socket.io as a prop to one of the child component but I am seeing multiple connections. In my child component I am listening to event in componentDidMount. I tried console.log in child componentDidMount and it is being called only once.

What is the standard way of using only single connection across all components? And why passing down as a props showing multiple connections at server side?

Comment: This really depends on quite a few things. Do you have control over the server and what sorts of messages it sends?

Comment: Do your different components need to receive different kinds of data, or are they all reacting to the same data?

Comment: Are you sure that you open only one connection in your parent component?

Do you close opened connection with componentWillUnmount in parent component?

Comment: Sorry for late response. @TKoL i am checking connected clients on server side and passing down the props shows multiple connections. But if it is initialized only in child component then it shows single connection. Yes,  All my components needs different data.

Comment: @Mykola i am opening connection in parent component and passing it down to child component which shows multiple connection. I can see 5 cons at the moment.

Comment: @TedKhi Maybe it would be better if you post here some code.

Answer (score 0):

What I would do is have a central socket controller, `socketController`, and inside its init method I would have it connect to the socket and begin watching for messages.

Each message that comes through should have like a 'dataType' that will determine where it goes, and a 'data' that is the data that is being passed.

The `socketController` should then allow anything to pass in a listener, `socketController.addListener = function(dataType, listener) {}` and you can keep an array of listeners for each dataType. Also implement a `removeListener` to go with the above function.

And then on each socket message in the socketController, check the dataType, iterate over all the listeners for that dataType and send them the data.

In your components, you can set the listeners in `componentDidMount` and remove them in `componentWillUnmount`.